# Display a tickmark or crossmark depending on the js condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have given some data in an array and i am trying to match that with the input given in a text field and if it matches it should display a checkmark and if it does not match it should display a crossmark.

But it either displays checkmark on all the numbers i enter or crossmark. My js code is like this

**

```
    > var data={"number":{"1234","7742","3452","6543","0091"}}; 
function validation(){ 
 var numbersearch =document.getElementById("validate").value;  
for(var i=0; i<data.number.length; i++) {
       if( data.number[i] === numberInput) {
       document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "block"; } 
else if(numberInput === '') { 
     document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "none"; }
 else{
     document.querySelector('.crossmark').style.display = "block"; } } }

**
```

```
HTML:
<div>
<input id="validate" type="text" maxlength=4 placeholder="0000">
<svg class="checkmark>
<scg class="crossmark>
</div>
```

Plz let me know where i am gng wrong? I have connected validation() function to html using angular component. But I want to display class .checkmark on matching and .crossmark on not matching condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you find your number, you should exit the loop. In the current state of affairs you basically only checking if the last number in the array is similar to the input.

So what you should do is exit the loop once you find a match. Like this:

```
    for(var i=0; i<data.number.length; i++) {
           if( data.number[i] === numberInput) {
           document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "block"; 
break; //This will exit the loop
} 
    
    else if(numberInput === '') { 
         document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "none"; 
     break; //You should also exit here
}
     else{
         document.querySelector('.crossmark').style.display = "block"; } } }
```

An even better way is not to use the for loop at all and check if the array cotains the input by using the 'contains' function. Like this:

```
if(numberInput === '') {
  document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "none"; 
} else if (data.number.contains(numberInput) {
  document.querySelector('.checkmark').style.display = "none"; 
} else {
 document.querySelector('.crossmark').style.display = "block";
}
```